# Permission denied when trying to play AudioSegment in python

Tags: python-2.7, audio, permissions, mp3, audiosegment

I am trying to split mp3 file into chunks by silence and getting

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 71, in play
    _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 18, in _play_with_ffplay
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 780, in export
    out_f = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 57, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'd:\\tmp\\tmpo5dfj5.wav'
```

while I am trying to play it

```
        audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(lessonFilePath)
        chunks = split_on_silence(audio, min_silence_len=2000, silence_thresh=-16)
        ordinalAudio = 0
        chunk = chunks[ordinalAudio]
        play(chunk) # here it is rising
```

I have access to this directory and I can execute

```
fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
```

in my own separate script.

What else can be checked?

Answer (score 5):

The issue has to do with how pydub manages temporary audio files. Pydub currently has a bug where it will open a temporary file multiple times, which works on linux but will result in the observed bug on windows (and possibly mac os, I haven't checked). One remedy is to `pip install simpleaudio` which will take over as the default temp file management system for pydub once installed.

Comment: Three years later and this is STILL the correct solution. Thanks for the help @theo!

Comment: This is not a bug. For an audio package not being able to play an audio file is a **total failure**. I really wonder how 'pypub' has gone public with such a pitiful condition!
And, BTW installing another audio package (simpleaudio) is not a solution to the current question, which **refers to 'pydub'**. It would be to a question such as "How can I play an audio file with Python?"

Answer (score 0):

I have not installed either **simpleaudio** or **pyaudio**. So pydub uses *ffplay*    (from my installed **ffmpeg** S/W) and pydub's **playback.py** module calls its '_play_with_ffplay()' function. Debugging it, I found the bug: they try to export a file while its file handle is opened! And of course this raises a "Permission denied' error. (It's unbelievable that they have not located it yet.) So the solution, in this case --and maybe in other cases-- is simply to close the file handle, before exporting, as follows:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
  f.close()                  # Added
  seg.export(f.name, "wav")  # Otherwise ... "Permission dennied" error
  ...
```

The audio file then is reproduced with no problem.

---

There's also another soulution, maybe even better: Export the audio segment "manually" to whatever compatible audio format you want, and then play it as you like. E.g., for MP3:

```
audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3({MP3_file})
audio.export({output_file}, {format})
```